# UnsavedChanges component - what parameters can be specified in options?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, documentation

Spring 19 introduced new lightning:unsavedChanges component, which works very nicely. However, I would need to manage buttons on modal that is shown when user is trying to navigate to some other page inside SF:
[image]

My idea is that this could be done via `options` argument of `setUnsavedChanges` function. However, the only documented parameter is `label`. Is there any way, how I can know, which parameters are available?

Comment: Sorry what you mean to "manage" buttons? Do you need to rename them? I don't think it is possible. `setUnsavedChanges` is to indicate that your state is dirty and optionally indicate why. If you wanna fire specific callbacks on save or discard, there are `ondiscard` and `onsave` params?

Comment: I meant more like if it's possible to remove 'Save' button, cause I was too lazy to write logic for it :D Anyway, I had no other choice. But it would be nice, if we could decide which buttons should be visible.

Comment: This would be great, let us know if you ever find a solution!